# Freeswitch internal/external profile calling

Tags: debian, freeswitch

On a dual NIC Freeswitch SIP Server, how can I enable calls between internal profile and external profile? I have eth0 192.168.1.10 , and eth1 public IP 41.x.x.x

sofia status profile internal
--------------------------------------------------------------
Domain Name             N/A
Auto-NAT                false
DBName                  sofia_reg_default
Pres Hosts              192.168.1.10,192.168.1.10
Dialplan                XML
Context                 public
Challenge Realm         auto_from
RTP-IP                  192.168.1.10
Ext-RTP-IP              41.x.x.x
SIP-IP                  192.168.1.10
Ext-SIP-IP              41.x.x.x
URL                     sip:mod_sofia@41.x.x.x:5060
BIND-URL                sip:mod_sofia@41.x.x.x:5060;maddr=192.168.1.10;transport=udp,tcp
HOLD-MUSIC              local_stream://moh
OUTBOUND-PROXY          N/A
CODECS IN               OPUS,PCMA,PCMU
CODECS OUT              OPUS,PCMA,PCMU
TEL-EVENT               101
DTMF-MODE               rfc2833
CNG                     13
SESSION-TO              0
MAX-DIALOG              0
NOMEDIA                 false
LATE-NEG                false
PROXY-MEDIA             false
ZRTP-PASSTHRU           false
AGGRESSIVENAT           true
CALLS-IN                0
FAILED-CALLS-IN         0
CALLS-OUT               0
FAILED-CALLS-OUT        0
REGISTRATIONS           67

sofia status profile external
----------------------------------------------------------

Domain Name             N/A
Auto-NAT                false
DBName                  sofia_reg_external
Pres Hosts
Dialplan                XML
Context                 public
Challenge Realm         auto_to
Ext-RTP-IP              41.x.x.x
Ext-SIP-IP              41.x.x.x
URL                     sip:mod_sofia@41.x.x.x:5060
BIND-URL                sip:mod_sofia@41.x.x.x:5060;maddr=41.x.x.x;transport=udp,tcp
HOLD-MUSIC              N/A
OUTBOUND-PROXY          N/A
CODECS IN               OPUS,PCMU,PCMA,G729
CODECS OUT              OPUS,PCMU,PCMA,G729
TEL-EVENT               101
DTMF-MODE               rfc2833
CNG                     13
SESSION-TO              0
MAX-DIALOG              0
NOMEDIA                 false
LATE-NEG                false
PROXY-MEDIA             false
ZRTP-PASSTHRU           false
AGGRESSIVENAT           false
CALLS-IN                0
FAILED-CALLS-IN         0
CALLS-OUT               0
FAILED-CALLS-OUT        0
REGISTRATIONS           23

When I try to call - I get USER_NOT_REGISTERED for the external profile user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set ext-sip-ip value="autonat:$${external_sip_ip}"

on the internal profile and deleted the external profile. Now users registering with a public IP and those on LAN can now talk!

Comment: m pretty sure you could've also used wildcard condition on dial-plan and bridge to users on internal profile . just a thought !